# Angular 4+ unit testing error . i can not unit test because of syntax error

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-jasmine

ERROR in src/app/campaigns/campaign-product-details/campaign-product-details.component.ts(106,14): error TS2339: Property 'disabled' does not exist on type '{ id: { toString: any; toFixed: any; toExponential: any; toPrecision: any; valueOf: any; toLocale...'.

Comment: 1.In my current project i have multiply syntax error. Now i need to unit test of some module which haven't any syntax error, so is it possible that "i can test this module in which i haven't got error i can do unit testing or i must resolve whole project syntax error and after then only i can do unit testing..

Comment: Provide code to better understand your problem. You may be trying to access property which is not declared.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to figure out these problems yourself. If not, please provide more detail about the problem.

Comment: i have only one question that is can i able to do unit testing with help of    this commands                  
                                               
fdescribe('AppComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule
      ],
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));    if i got error from other module